# Python substring extraction issue

Tags: python-3.x, substring

I try to run a simple code for substring extraction from string

```
def main():

    fld='20191201234559'

    yyyy=fld[:4]
    mm=fld[4:2]
    dd=fld[6:2]
    hh=fld[8:2]
    hm=fld[10:2]
    hs=fld[12:2]
    print("res", yyyy,mm,dd,hh,hm,hs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
res 2019
```

Substring with [a:b] return nothing.

It's happened on
- Windows 10: python ver 3.7.5
- Ubuntu 18.04: python ver 3.6.9

As result I use this code:

```
def main():

    fld='20191201234559'

    yyyy=fld[:4]
    mm=fld[4]+fld[5]
    dd=fld[6]+fld[7]
    hh=fld[8]+fld[9]
    hm=fld[10]+fld[11]
    hs=fld[12]+fld[13]
    print("res", yyyy, mm, dd, hh, hm, hs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
res 2019 12 01 23 45 59
```

What's wrong with substring extraction?

Comment: Any reason you are not using `datetime.strptime`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected and working properly

```
def main():

    fld='20191201234559'

    yyyy=fld[:4]
    mm=fld[4:6]
    dd=fld[6:8]
    hh=fld[8:10]
    hm=fld[10:12]
    hs=fld[12:14]
    print("res", yyyy,mm,dd,hh,hm,hs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```